Kafka GCS sink connector flush size
I am using JDBC source connector to write the data into Kafka Topic for every 24 hours polling interval set and consuming the messages from Kafka topic using GCS sink connector. There is approximately 500k records written into Kafka topic by JDBC source connector and i would like to consume messages and write file size on avg 50MB. So set the property below, we use json payload
flush.size: 25000
gcs.part.size: 5242880
rotate.schedule.interval.ms: 60000
partition.duration.ms: 60000

GCS sink connector is writing so many small files (1.MB or kbs) and i could not figure out the solutions after increasing the above values though and need to write file size avg 50MB with minimum time.

From your configuration, could be that the rotate.schedule.interval.ms is kicking before reaching the size you want. Could you try increasing it? Set it for example to 3600000 (partition as well, same value)
